# sails-hook-babel causing errors in sails app

Tags: node.js, sails.js, babeljs

After installing `sails-hook-babel` in my sails app in an effort to use es6 js in my back end, I cannot launch my app. I get an error: `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

After searching for solution, I tried to use `@bable/polyfill` by creating a `config/babel/js` file with:

```
module.exports.babel = {
  polyfill: true
}
```

After doing that, the app will launch without error, but then when I try to call any `action2` format action that references the `exits` property like:

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    let mauticConnector = new MauticConnector({
        apiUrl: sails.config.mauticUrl,
      username: sails.config.mauticUser,
      password: sails.config.mauticPw,
      logLevel: 'verbose',
      timeoutInSeconds: 5
    });

    const campaigns = (await mauticConnector.campaigns.listCampaigns()).campaigns;


    // All done.
    return exits.success(campaigns);
```

I get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined`

What can I do to make `sails-hook-babel` work with my app in 2020?

Using node 10 and sails 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node on its own already supports [ES6 usage](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/). You do not need to use Babel to handle this. Just uninstall the package.

Comment: Thanks I eventually figured that out

Comment: I figured, but it's still good to get questions answered, should others stumble upon them.